# How delete word ending with precise chars in list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuple:

```
sent = [("Faire", 'VERB'),
 ("la", 'DET'),
 ("peinture", 'NOUN'),
 ("de", 'ADP'),
 ("la", 'DET'),
 ("voiture", 'NOUN')]
```

I would like to have a comprehension giving a list of words as result.
And I want to skip 'VERB' ending with 're'.

I tried this, but have a boolean:

```
sent_clean = [not x.endswith('re') for (x,y) in sent if y in ['VERB']]
```

Expected output:

```
["la", "peinture", "de", "la", "voiture"]
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side of the list comprehension is the elements you want to end up with, the right hand side is for conditions

```
sent_clean =  [x for (x,y) in sent if not (y == 'VERB' and x.endswith('re'))]
```